# Number of characters in WebView

Tags: android, webview

I have a simple html document, so I want to display approximately 60 characters per line in my WebView on different screens and configurations. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can add a script in javascript. So you have to implement. I huso give you an idea.

```
function chunk(str, n) {
var ret = [];
var i;
var len;

for(i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i += n) {
   ret.push(str.substr(i, n))
}

return ret
};

chunk("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs.", 5).join('$');

_webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    _webView.loadUrl(
        "javascript: chunk(view.text));"
    );
 }
});
```

Comment: Thx a lot! Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the web page. If the web page is an adaptative page and have for example bootstrap.Then the page must implement the logic for counting characters.

Comment: it's just some <p> tags;
So my idea was to convert ppi to font size, but I don't know if it's a good idea